# Android: efficiency of CursorLoader-swapCursor vs ArrayList-notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: android, sqlite, loader

I have a list which usually contains < 100 entries. Sometimes 200-1000 entries. Occasionally it can contain many more such as 20000 entries.
Data is queried from a few SQLiteDatabase tables.

1. I load and display the data in a ListView.
2. I do various reads/writes in other app logic such as in a service etc.
3. I do operations such as: move some items around, to beginning or end of the list, modify their content, delete them, add new ones etc. - and save changes in the DB.

   - For the ListView I call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.
   - I consider implementing a Loader (SQLite query loader) to use Loaders. The loader will observe data changes, re-run the query and I would use `mAdaptor.swapCursor()` to use the new Cursor.

My question is: while both methods would be asynchronous, which one of the above would be more efficient? (shorter loading time etc)?

Answer (score 0):

It's my own question too, but I think based on my information that:

1. Querying the database reads from `file-system` which is much slower than `RAM` (You can visit [this link](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/80869/191264))
2. `Adapter` has some more efficient methods for notifying dataset changes like `notifyItemRangeIserted()` and so, and the `ArrayList` will reside in `RAM` as your application resides.

So I conclude that caching data in memory will be faster but you absolutely should be careful about **heap size** and **memory leak**!

Comment: Your answer is misleading and vague - please don't hijack the thread.
I clearly stated that the source is a database. The Adapter is a base class for all kinds of adapters!

Comment: @RumburaK, it's clear that you didn't read my answer and just skimmed it! I said I have the same question and haven't found answer in previous SO questions and what I've written is based on my own knowledge and may not be correct! By **`Adapter`** I mean something you choose to extend to sit between your `data source` and `view`, it can be `SimpleCursorAdapter` or any other subclass of the base `Adapter` class!